Fraction word problem that a total includes uneven groups
There are red, blue and yellow pens in a box.
The ratio of the number of red pens to blue pens is 2:3.
The ratio of the number of yellow pens to the total number of red and blue pens is 5:6.
What fraction of the pens in the box are blue pens?
The answer of above is 18/55. However I am not able to work out. (I ever tried to add the red and blue as 2+3=5 to put it into the "Yellow: red & blue = 5:6", but it seems making no sense)
Thank you.

$\frac{R}{B}=\frac{2}{3}$, $R=\frac{2B}{3}$
$\frac{Y}{R+B}=\frac{5}{6}$, $\frac{Y}{\frac{2B}{3}+B}=\frac{5}{6}$, $\frac{Y}{\frac{5B}{3}}=\frac{5}{6}$, $\frac{Y}{B}=\frac{5}{6}\times \frac{5}{3}$, $\frac{Y}{B}=\frac{25}{18}$ then $\frac{R}{B}=\frac{12}{18}$
Let $Y=25x,B=18x,R=12x$ then $\frac{B}{Y+B+R}=\frac{18}{55}$

brilliant! Can you please also advise, how to get Y:B=25:18 from Y:(2B/3+B)=5:6?

@Mark K : I have put more details.

thanks again, you're amazing!
